# Cannot call class function (parameterized class)

Tags: c++, class

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class a
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    int getx()
    {
        return x;
    }
    int gety()
    {
        return y;
    }
    a()
    {
        x = 100;
        y = 100;
    }
    void xmin()
    {
        x--;
    }
    void ab(a x)
    {
        x.xmin(); x.xmin(); x.xmin(); x.xmin();
    }
};

void main()
{
    a xx;
    a yy;
    cout << "xx" << endl;
    cout << "x : " << xx.getx() << "y : " << xx.gety()<<endl;
    cout << "yy" << endl;
    cout << "x : " << yy.getx() << "y : " << yy.gety()<<endl;
    xx.ab(yy);
    cout << "xx" << endl;
    cout << "x : " << xx.getx() << "y : " << xx.gety() << endl;
    cout << "yy" << endl;
    cout << "x : " << yy.getx() << "y : " << yy.gety() << endl;
}
```

Why the function `x.xmin()` in `void ab(a x)` cannot be executed properly? (The value of `x` didn't change as the function of `xmin()` decrease the value of `x` by 1.

This is the simple version of my code so that will be easier to understand :)

Comment: You passed the value as a param not the object it self, you have to pass the reference `void ab(a& x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void ab(a x)
```

That takes its argument by value. The function modifies a local copy of the argument, so the caller won't see any changes. If you want the function to modify the caller's object, then pass by reference:

```
void ab(a & x)
          ^
```